Agora sdk in angular
I have implemented agora video calling feature in angular. I am facing audio related issue while video call. Sometimes user can't listen remote user audio. When anyone user rejoin the call then audio problem generates
I trying to State re initialise when user rejoins join

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
